# Summation/Add two values inside foreach loop

Tags: c#

I want to add Array items inside forach loop.
My `RegionalEarn` array comes like this,

```
[0]Region1=25

[1]Region2=50
```

I need final `RModel.TAX` Should be `75(25+50)` But in my case it comes like `2550`

### My Code

```
string[] RegionalEarn = tickets["EARN"].ToString().Split(',');

foreach (var item in RegionalEarn)
{
RModel.TAX = RModel.TAX + item.Split('=')[1];
}
```

Comment: try like this `RModel.TAX += item.Split('=')[1];`

Comment: What's the difference between your suggestion and the one outlined in the question? I don't think there is any.

Comment: @TechGuy 75 (25+50)  is what? TAX*(array value 1 + array value 2)?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic RegionalEarn consist of taxes.I need to Add/Sum those taxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you done like concatenation.it comes only string values. so try convert to int or double .

```
 string[] RegionalEarn = tickets["EARN"].ToString().Split(',');


  foreach (var item in RegionalEarn)

   {

RModel.TAX = Convert.ToInt32(RModel.TAX) + Convert.ToInt32( item.Split('=')[1]);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding strings, not numbers. You can use the [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method on for example the Int32 type to try convert a string to an int. The other numbers types have a similar TryParse method. If your number comes with extra signs, dots or commas, apply the the overload that accepts a FormatProvider matching the Numberstyle or a Culture the number is from.

```
string[] RegionalEarn = tickets["EARN"].ToString().Split(',');

var sum =0;    
foreach (var item in RegionalEarn)
{
   var num = 0;
   if (Int32.TryParse(item.Split('=')[1], out num))
   {
       sum = sum + num;
   }
   else 
   {
       // log error, item.Split('=')[1] is not an int
   }
}
RModel.TAX = sum.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it.

```
string[] RegionalEarn = tickets["EARN"].ToString().Split(',');

foreach (var item in RegionalEarn)
{
    RModel.TAX = (int.Parse(RModel.TAX) * item.Split('=').Sum (p => int.Parse(p))).ToString();
}
```

The above will take `RModel.TAX` multiply it with the **sum** of the values in the item array using Sum() method. This should give you the correct result.